# WebView не загружает изображение

Tags: webview, изображения, android

Почему `WebView` зависает и показывает пустой экран (`Android` 4.2),при этом на 2.3 все работает? На сколько я понимаю он должен вываливаться в ошибку и заходить на ya.ru, но этого почему-то не происходит. При этом при подстановке `url` все работает. Файлы существуют и программа спокойно видит их в другом классе

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.pokaz_izobraz);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    path=intent.getStringExtra("path");
    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.pokaz_izobr);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background));
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);     webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    try {
    webView.loadUrl("file:///data/data/com.example.my/files/cxema_0.png");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.ya.ru");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
}
```

Странная особенность, при `setInitialScale(0)` все работает, но масштаб неправильный

Comment: А ваша схема на самом деле такая огромная, что её нужно уменьшать в 100 раз? Наверняка Вы её просто не видите в таком масштабе)) А 2.3 просто уменьшает на сколько может (до 1% он не умеет).

Comment: Не обязательно,но проблема в том,что если бы он просто не видел бы тогда должны были быть полосы прокрутки,а так просто перестает реагировать экран.При этом не нажимаются другие элементы кроме WebView